# How to slow down the frequency of a sin() wave in GLSL?

Tags: glsl, shader

*Question Reference:*

**http://thebookofshaders.com/03/**

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform float u_time;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(abs(sin(u_time)),0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

### [Live Code Example](http://thebookofshaders.com/edit.php?log=170209043856)

> Now it is time again to play with the above code.
>
> 1 -  Slow down the frequency until the color change becomes almost imperceptible.
>
> 2 - Speed it up until you see a single color without flickering.
>
> 3 - Play with the three channels (RGB) in different frequencies to get interesting patterns and behaviors.

For the first ask:

> 1 -  Slow down the frequency until the color change becomes almost
>   imperceptible.

I tried dividing/multiplying the `u_time` which yielded a syntax error. `uniform float u_time/2; // ERROR`, I'm just having difficultly understanding what the author wants me to learn.  I'm feeling hard pressed to move forward in the readings w/o understanding.

Maybe the author's questions wants me to not use `abs(sin(u_time))` but rather another function:

> The GPU has hardware accelerated angle, trigonometric and exponential functions.
>
> Some of those functions are: sin(), cos(), tan(), asin(), acos(),
>   atan(), pow(), exp(), log(), sqrt(), abs(), sign(), floor(), ceil(),
>   fract(), mod(), min(), max() and clamp().

If so, which function would I use to complete the asks stated below?

*Could I also get help understanding how to solve: 2 and 3*

> 2 - Speed it up until you see a single color without flickering.
>
> 3 - Play with the three channels (RGB) in different frequencies to get
>   interesting patterns and behaviors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not move forward without understanding! I would very much doubt if you even could do that, actually. It's a core part of the language!

---

To reassign a variable in GLSL, the syntax is this:

```
variable = new_value;
```

And since you want the new value to depend on the old value, you just use the variable there too:

```
variable = variable * 2;
```

But GLSL is picky with its numeric types, so since `u_time` is a float, you have to multiply (or divide, or add, or whatever you do) with a float:

```
u_time = u_time * 2.0f;
```

Now you have the time multiplied by 2, which means twice the frequency! Or if you didn't want to change the value of the variable, only what is passed to the color, you can do it like in JS (I see you have previous experience with it, so that's what I'm comparing, but it's pretty standard across languages):

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(abs(sin(u_time * 2.0f)),0.0,0.0,1.0);
```

#2 is just changing the 2 for a division, or using a number between 0 and 1.

For #3, you use a non-constant value for the other fields of the `vec4` constructor, for example you could use more sine waves with some offset added to them, to make multiple colors.

---

## A bit more technical info about your error:

The syntax

```
modifier type name = value;
```

is reserved for variable *declarations**, which should happen only once (like the `var` in JavaScript).

You can, however, change the value of an already declared variable as much as you want, and the syntax for that is just

```
name = value;
```

Where the `value` can be any expression you want (the result of a function call, a constant, the result of some chain of operators like multiplication, etc).

*<sub>The equal sign and initial value is optional</sub>

Comment: Such simple.  Thanks for the awesome answer!

Comment: @Himal you should ask a proper question! But uniforms are specific to the environment the shader is running on (the renderer, and possibly any other code), so you should check on the documentation of the library you're using.

Comment: Never mind, I think I found it [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=circledev.glsl-canvas) thanks anyway.